# Laptop Broken black screen

Tags: windows, laptop, black-screen-of-death, dell-precision

After booting, my laptop is stuck on a black screen with a flickering circle and cursor. I have tried everything, including reinstalling Windows using a USB, but I cannot use a single key. Can anyone offer any possible help? I am willing to provide videos and pictures if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try a bus-connected Dock, or else replace the screen. There is really nothing else you can do.

Look in the Manufacturer's Support site for bus-connected Docks (connector on the bottom of the laptop - not USB).

Depending on the age of the machine and the cost of a screen plus replacing the main drive, it may make more sense to replace the computer with what you need as more economical overall.

Comment: Hi, I tried plugging in an external monitor nothing changed

Comment: An external monitor will not work for what you are trying to do.  You need a monitor connection at the time the booting USB starts

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Laptops that have bus-connections are less common these days, as USB type C has become a de facto standard that is easier to integrate into smaller device profiles. You can tell if your laptop has one of these by there being a large connector on the bottom or rear of the laptop. Sharing your specific laptop model could help us identify if you have this option as well.

Comment: You need a monitor connection at the time of boot

Comment: dell precision m6800

Comment: It might be possible for a USB dock to work but I have not seen that.

Comment: I was thinking of maybe buying a new HDD or ssd

Comment: It may be more economical overall to replace the computer (answer amended)

Comment: Would it be wise to bring it to someone for a repair?
Or do you think it can't be fixed no matter what?
By the way it is a very powerful laptop, and would rather not lose it because it was very expensive.

Comment: You can talk to a local shop as ask them for a quote.

Comment: hi I have been messing around and got myself to a screen with loading circle saying just a moment. I am going to see what happens

Comment: I fixed it!!!!!

Comment: And it restarted automatically and went back to the same black screen

Comment: You do need to get it repaired as I have noted.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think I will.

Comment: But just checking.
There is definitely no way to get it fixed at home

Comment: Yes - you need to find a local shop and see what they can do, and replace the computer if too expensive.

Comment: hi this time I definitely fixed it myself.
I went into advanced startup and used system restore

Comment: Hi it is fixed I can use it.
I even restarted it to check.
I am even using it for this message right now